# What happens when my PHP website will start having a LOT of members?

Tags: php, mysql, bandwidth

This is something I am really curious about and I do not really understand how is that possible.

So lets say I am the owner of Facebook (ahah) and I have million of people visiting my website every day, thousands and thousands of images, videos, logs etc..

How do I store all this data?

Do I have more databases in different servers around the world and then I connect to them from a single location?

Do I use an internal API system that requests info from other servers where the data is stored?

For example I know that Facebook has a lot of data centers around the world and hundreds of servers..

How do they connect to these servers? Are the profiles stored in different locations and when I connect to my profile, I will then be using that specific server? Or is there one main server that has the support of other hundreds of servers around the world?

Is there a way to use PHP in a way that I will connect to different servers and to different mySQL (???) databases to store and retrieve data whenever I want?

Sorry if this looks like a silly question, but since it could happen a day to work on a successful website, I really want to know what I will have to do, and what is the logic behind.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Eventually you will realize that MySQL is a dog and start looking at something different like NoSQL database. At the same time you will start looking at a different more efficient programming language.

Comment: Looks like Facebook is still using PHP as its main programming language, so that must be efficient enough.

Comment: Although they convert (some?) of it to C++ using their own HipHip library.

Comment: Yes and no. I think they write code in php but then using their own HipHop compiler to compile it as C code. If they could turn back time they would have started with the C++ in the first place, but it's not easy to switch when you have thousands of lines of code already in production.

Comment: If they turned back time and started with C++ someone else would've beaten them to the market with a Minimum Viable Product.

Comment: @DmitriSnytkine - eventually you'll realize what RDBMS is and how to scale it. Or maybe you won't and you'll stay on the NoSQL hype train :)

Comment: Is Minimum Viable Product a new buzz word of the week?

Comment: You worry too much, it will take a long time for MySQL to be too slow and there are looaaaaads of options to speed up MySQL (cluster, partitions, master-slave, writing smart queries). This is a clear case of premature optimization.

Comment: @Dmitri Snytkine - unless you have worked with large datasets (measured in TB), let's not have the discussion about NoSQL vs RDBMS please. Both have their advantages, however they don't do the same things. Let's not compare apples and cars, especially if you haven't driven one.

Comment: @N.B I am not comparing anything, just answering the question. Question specifically ask "what if site becomes big like Facebook". I think at that scale you have to do some type of NoSQL.

Comment: You did say MySQL is a dog, you suggested NoSQL and you suggested a different programming language. I mean, is that coming from experience or what? Matra "right tool for right task" always applies, and you **need** to know what the right tool is. For example, Java was ditched since it raped memory. But we all know that Java > PHP (synthetic tests of course). There's so much BS out there when it comes to comparing technologies that it's not even funny. I'm not advocating anything, I'm just laughing at the lack of knowledge and spreading that cancer-knowledge around.

Comment: It always amuses me when somebody says that <insert technology name> is bad for <insert task type> without providing some kind of proof, or, at least sharing knowledge, experience...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll try to answer your (big) question but not from Facebook point of view since their architecture is pretty much known.

First thing you have to know is that you would have to distribute the workload of your web application. Question is how, so in order to determine what's going to be slow, you have to divide your app in segments.

**First up is the HTTP server**, or the one that accepts all the requests. By going to "www.your-facebook.com", you're contacting a service on an IP. Naturally, you would probably have more than one IP but let's say you have a single entry point.

Now what happens? You have an HTTP server software, let's say Apache and it handles incoming connections. Since Apache creates a thread per connected user, it requires certain amount of memory for that operation. Eventually, it will run out of memory and then shit hits the fan, stuff stops working, your site is unavailable.
Therefore, you have to **somehow** scale this part of your application that connects your PHP code / MySQL db to people who want to interact with it.

Let's assume you successfully scaled your Apache and you have a cluster of computers which can accept new computers in order to scale-out. You solved your first problem.

Next part is the actual layer that does the work. Accepts input from the user and saves it somewhere (MySQL) and that's the biggest problem you'll have - why?
Due to the database.

Databases store their data on mediums such as hard drives. Hard drives, be it an SSD or mechanical one - are limited by their ability to write or retrieve data. If I'm not mistaken, RAM operates at levels of around 6GB/sec transfer rate. Not to mention that the seek time is also much much lower than HDD's one is.

Therefore, if you have an X amount of users asking for a piece of information and you can only deliver it at a certain rate - your app crashes, or it becomes unresponsive and the layer handling database queries becomes slow since the hardware cannot match the speed at which you need the data.

What are the options here? There are many, I won't mention all of them

1. Split Reads and Writes. Set your database layer in such a way that you have dedicated machines that write the data and completely different ones that read it. You have to use replication and replication has its own quirks - it never works without breaking.
2. Optimize handling of your data set by sharding your data. Great for read / write performance, screwed up when you need to query multiple shards and merge the data.
3. Get better hardware, especially storage (such as [FusionIO](http://www.fusionio.com/))
4. Pay for better storage engine (such as [TokuDB](http://www.tokudb.com))
5. Alleviate load on the database by using caching. The data that your users request probably doesn't change so often that you have to query the db every single time (say you're viewing someone's profile, what's the chance they'll change it every second?). That's why Facebook uses Memcached extensively - a system that stores small pieces of data in RAM, it's easily scalable and what not. Most important, it's damn quick!
6. Use different solutions next to MySQL. MySQL (and some other databases) aren't good for every type of data storage or retrieval. Someone mentioned NoSQL before. NoSQL solutions are quick, but still immature. They don't do as much as relational databases do. They use methods of delaying disk write (they keep cached copy of data they need to write in RAM) so that they can achieve fast insert rates. That's why it's not unusual to lose data when using NoSQL.

Topic about MySQL vs "insert database or whatever here" is broad, I don't want to go into that but remember - every single one of data stores out there saves data on the hard drive eventually. The difference (physical of course) is how they optimize their flushing to the disk itself.

I also didn't mention various reports you can run by gathering the data (how many men between 19 and 21 have clicked an advert X between 01:15 and 13:37 CET and such) which is what Facebook is actually gathering (scary stuff!).

Third up - the language gluing the data store (MySQL) and output (HTTP server). **PHP**.

As you can see, most of the work here is already done by Apache and MySQL. Optimization on PHP level is small, even facebook got small results (they claim 50%, but that's UP TO 50%). I tried HipHop extensively, it is not as fast as it claims to be. Naturally, Facebook guys mentioned that already, so it's no wonder. The advantage they get is because they replaced Apache with their own server built in into HipHop. Some people claim "language X is better than language Y" and they're right, but that's not always the case. Each language has its own advantages and disadvantages.

For example, PHP is widely-spread but it's slow for certain operations (implementing a Trie with over 1 billion entries for example). It's great for things like echo some HTML after parsing the output from the db. It's quick to insert and retrieve data from the database, and that's about 90% of the PHP usage - talk to the db, display the data, end.

Therefore, no matter what language you use (say we used C++ instead of PHP), your bottleneck will be the data storage / retrieval layer.

On the other hand, why is using C++ NOT handy? Because there are more people who know how to use PHP than ones who use C++. It's also MUCH slower to develop web apps in C++. Sure, they will execute faster, but who will notice the difference between 1 millisecond and 1 microsecond?

This post is more like an informative blog post, I know it's not filled with resources to back up my claims but anyone who did any work with larger data sets or websites will know that the P.I.T.A. is always the data storage component. Some things that I said probably won't fit with everyone, but in a NUTSHELL this is how you'd go about optimizing your site.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your question doesn't have a simple answer.  For the MySQL portion of it, you would need to investigate database scale-out.  You can start looking at it here:  http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/scaleout/mixi.html.  There are a number of different ways to set up Apache/PHP web sites across a server farm.  One of them involves setting up round robin DNS.  This is adding a DNS record with a number of different IP addresses.  Your DNS then hands out a different IP address each time the record is requested so that the load is balanced across a number of servers.  You can also set up clustering with MySQL, Apache and Heartbeat, but that is more of a high-availability solution than a scaling solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a website with so many users you'll already have enough experience to know the answer of the question, you'll also have a lot of money to pay people to find the optimal architecture of your system.

I'm not saying that what I describe below is the Holy Grail, but it is certainly an option:

You will have a big, fragmented database with lots of backups and you'll have a few name servers which will know the location of servers and some rules about the data stored on each server. When data is searched the query will be sent to a name server which will find the server(s) where the answer can be found for the particular query. I've also upvoted N.B.'s answer, I think he is mostly right.

Answer (score 0):

For lots of users, you should have a server with lots of memory and *speed*. Configure php.ini to allow more memory usage. A server with lots of users should have 4-12GB available. Also, save resources by closing the desktop environment. If you have this many users, you might want to consider a CDN and also make a database request queue.